# Please explain the difference between abstract class VS concrete class?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have one abstract class with two unimplemented (abstract) methods, one implemented method and one static method like below code.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass1 {
  static void test(){
    System.out.println("111");

 }
 public abstract void test2();

 public abstract void test3();

 public void test4(){
    System.out.println("222");
 }

}
```

I am extending this class in some other abstract class like below code

```
public abstract class AbstractClassImplementation 
          extends  AbstractClass1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("java abstract doubt");
    }
}
```

My doubt is whether AbstractClass1 class containing abstract methods means that we must override whenever we extend it in a subclass ; but no error is shown here if the subclass is abstract

Suppose my subclass is not abstract ; this time i must override all unimplemented methods which are available in "AbstractClass1" class see below example

```
 public  class AbstractClassImplementation extends AbstractClass1{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("java abstract doubt");
 }

 @Override
 public void test2() {
    System.out.println("overrided here");

 }

 @Override
 public void test3() {
    System.out.println("overrided here");

 }
}
```

Can anybody explain this ?

Comment: abstract classes don't need to provide all implementations, concrete class do need to have an implementation for all classes.  If an abstract class extends an abstract class, it still doesn't have to implement all methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in second code snippet AbstractClassImplementation itself is abstract so it's not showing any error .

Here is what [Orcale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) have to say about this

> When an abstract class is subclassed, the subclass usually provides
>   implementations for all of the abstract methods in its parent class.
>   However, if it does not, then the subclass must also be declared
>   abstract.

Answer (score 2):

`AbstractClassImplementation` is itself `abstract`, and therefore does not have to override all the `abstract` methods. Only a concrete (non-`abstract`) class must implement all the `abstract` methods.

Answer (score 2):

Since your sub class is also abstract (can't be initialized) you don't have to implement those methods, but the sub-sub class in this case (if not abstract) will have to implement those abstract methods

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to check for implementations of abstract methods in `AbstractClass2` because an object can't be instantiated as an `AbstractClass2`.

Any concrete class deriving from `AbstractClass2` must implement all abstract methods in both `AbstractClass1` and `AbstractClass2`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a requirement for a subclass to implement methods of an abstract superclass. All that is required is that any concrete class (the one you can initialize) must implement all the not already implemented methods from all its superclasses (including interfaces). Other classes are not required to implement them.